# Bug with grouping in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For the group function in Excel, I am able to create groups and levels. However, it seems like if you group a number of rows, and then create a subgroup with the same last element, the "collapse" `+` button doesn't appear and the last subgroup cannot be collapsed.

Is this a bug with Excel or is there something I can do to fix it? It seems pervasive over several versions, which bugs usually are not, but it seems like it is not a desirable feature.

Comment: For office bug, usually user must wait for the official hotfix released by microsoft. You can check if there is hotfix available on Windows Update.

Comment: @Bilo I guess I'm wondering if this really is a bug or something else. Seems like an undesired quality, but I could be wrong. Also I'm on corporate, so I get updates when I get them

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you uncheck the Summary Rows Below Detail in the Outline/Setting dialog box it moves the plus/minus sign to the top of the grouping and then the last group is included and will expand & collapse properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Will83’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1345251/167207) is Correct, however unchecking "Summary rows below detail" still doesent make it bag-free.

This is how: if you group your list from higher levels first and then lower levels after, (meaning if you first group the inside groups and then try to group your inside groups you have made to a group) the problem of the last inside group persists until you group that specific group again.

For this reason it will be a good idea to group the low level first and work your way inward. Hope this makes sense.